# Minimize objective function for least square classification

Tags: linear-regression, discriminant

Consider a training set $\{(\vec{x^{(n)}}, \vec{t^{(n)}}) \in \rm I\!R^D \times I\!R^K : n = 1, ..., N  \}$ where :

- $\vec{t^{(n)}}$ is an indicator for the class membership of $\vec{x^{(n)}}$, i.e $\vec{t^{(n)}} = (0, 1, ... 0)$ if $\vec{x^{(n)}}$ belongs to $C2$
- ***X*** is a $N \times (D+1)$ matrix whose *n*th row is $(\vec{x^{(n)}})^T$
- ***T*** is a $N \times K$ matrix whose *n*th row is $(\vec{t^{(n)}})^T$

The least square problem is to minimise the **objective function**:

$G($***W***$)$ = $\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\sum_{k=1}^{K}[y_k(\vec{t^{(n)}};\vec{w_k}) - t_k^{(n)}]^2$

where $y_k(\vec{t^{(n)}};\vec{w_k})$ is the **linear discriminant function**.

I know that ***W*** is minimised by ***W*** = (***X***$^T$***X***)$^{-1}$***X***$^T$***X***

However, I don't understand why there is this $\frac{1}{2}$ coefficient in front of the double summation.

Comment: Does the factor $1/2$ matter? Whichever $W$ minimizes $G(W)$ also minimizes $2G(W)$.

Comment: 0.5 is the border between 2 classes in range [0,1] - taking into consideration weights up to 100% (equal 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a simplification tool. When you take the derivative of the objective function and the exponent $2$ comes out to multiply the double sum it will be cancelled out. Similarly, when you set the objective function's derivative to $0$ you could just as easily divide out the $2$ in the front.

Comment: Ok, it makes sense, thank you.